# C# MongoDB LINQ: Cannot query nested list

Tags: c#, mongodb

I'm trying to query a MongoDB collection using official C# driver. Here's the object structure I've created:

```
IMongoDatabase db = mongoClient.GetDatabase("appdb");
IMongoCollection<MusicFile> musicfiles = db.GetCollection<MusicFile>("files");

public class MusicFile
{
        public ObjectId Id { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public IList<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
}

public class Comment
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

This is the query I'm trying to get any MusicFile objects that contains a Comment object with property Text = "Comment1":

```
musicfiles.AsQueryable().Where(f => f.Comments != null && f.Comments.Any(c => c.Text == "Comment1")).ToList();
```

I can't get this query to work, it always returns an empty list. I also tried this, which too didn't work:

```
musicfiles.Find(f => f.Comments.Any(c => c.Text == "Comment1")).ToList()
```

But, if I get the complete collection is memory, the query works:

```
musicfiles.Find(FilterDefinition<MusicFile>.Empty).ToList().Where(f => f.Comments != null && f.Comments.Any(c => c.Text == "Comment1")).ToList();
```

This seems like a very inefficient way to query. Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm on a bus right now so I can't provide an answer, but I've found that queryable can't convert more complicated queries. I'd recommend using the filter builder and elemMatch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. I'm back at home. Try this:

```
var musicFilter = Builders<MusicFile>.Filter;
var commentFilter = Builders<Comment>.Filter;

var files = musicfiles
                .Find(
                    musicFilter.NE(m => m.Comments, null)
                    & musicFilter.ElemMatch(m => m.Comments, commentFilter.Eq(c => c.Text, "Comment1"))
                )
                .ToEnumerable()
                .ToList();
```

Note I call .ToList() because, otherwise, if you iterate through files multiple times, you'll get multiple calls to the database for the same objects.

Comment: Thanks, this worked! I'm new to using C# mongodb driver, but I guess LINQ is not gonna be my friend in learning.